# create an alias on network card using netplan on Ubuntu server

Tags: netplan

how to configure two ip (192.168.140.10/24 - 192.168.57.192/25) on same network card on Ubuntu server 18.4.1.using netplan

Answer (score 4):

From the [Netplan Examples](https://netplan.io/examples) page, here is the example showing how to create 2 IPs on the same interface.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
     addresses:
       - 10.100.1.38/24
       - 10.100.1.39/24
     gateway4: 10.100.1.1
```

You should also be able to use a list notation as follows:

```
  ethernets:
    enp3s0:
     addresses: [ 10.100.1.38/24, 10.100.1.39/24 ]
```